# Managing programs that run in multiple console windows?

Tags: c++, windows, console, cmd

I have a script that starts 7 or 8 different c++ server modules that all open in console windows on a windows machine.  I've been looking for a way to run all of these in a single, tabbed window.  I've tried a few programs out there, but they are mostly cmd.exe replacements and aren't really designed for running programs like this.  Has anyone else run into this and found a good solution?

Comment: Voted to close with wrong reason. Should have done off-topic.

Comment: @Joe, I think you might have better luck with this kind of question on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/).  It's not really a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/):

[image]

Comment: I've tried this a little, but I couldn't get a bat file to issue "start" commands to modules and have them all open as different tabs.